# Automatically associate Flutter SDK with project in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, flutter

Is there a way to configure WebStorm to automatically associate the Flutter SDK path with an imported project?

I've found out that if I clone a project from GitHub and open it in WebStorm, it doesn't associate with the SDK, rather it says "No Flutter SDK configure". To resolve this, I will have to go to `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter` to manually specify the path to the SDK for the current project. However, this is not the case with a project started from scratch where Flutter is chosen from the beginning.

Flutter doctor seems to indicate I've installed the SDK. It is not a particularly big problem but it just adds an extra step that is annoying.

```
[✓] Flutter (on Linux, channel master)
    • Flutter at /home/driftavalii/workspace/flutter
    • Framework revision c5cf8e0190 (4 days ago), 2017-05-13 11:11:58 -0700
    • Engine revision f1bfdddfc8
    • Tools Dart version 1.23.0-dev.11.11

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 25.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/driftavalii/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-25, build-tools 25.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/driftavalii/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    • Android Studio at /usr/local/android-studio
    • Gradle version 3.2
    • Java version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.1)
    • Dart plugin version 171.4424
    • Flutter plugin version 13.0

[✓] WebStorm (version 2017.1)
    • Flutter plugin version 13.1

[✓] Connected devices
    • None
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug with our WebStorm support in the flutter plugin. Can you file an issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, just filed an issue.